# Error while creating a pandas dataframe out of numpy ndarrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to concatenate numpy ndarrays of size (19200,) to make a data frame. Each 1D array would be a row in my data frame. My code looks like that:

```
new_array_1 = pd.DataFrame(new_array_1, index=['new_array_1'])
new_array_2 = pd.DataFrame(new_array_2, index=['new_array_2'])
new_array_3 = pd.DataFrame(new_array_3, index=['new_array_3'])

df = pd.concat([df, new_array_1, new_array_2, new_array_3])
```

but I got the error:

```
Shape of passed values is (19200, 1), indices imply (1, 1)
```

But then after I add the square brackets around the new_arrays like this:

```
new_array_1 = pd.DataFrame([new_array_1], index=['new_array_1'])
df = pd.concat([df, new_array_1])
```

and I got the error:

```
Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 1, 19200)
```

What should I do to solve the problem, please?
Please note that I cannot add all my arrays at the same time, I update my data frame by adding the rows of data whenever I got the data.

Comment: This is because you use `index=['new_array_1']` instead of `columns=['new_array_1']`

Comment: Also, are you 100% sure about that shape?

Comment: Also, consider stacking the arrays into a pre-allocated buffer. Repeated concatenation is expensive in numpy and pandas

Comment: running my_array_1.shape gives me: (1, 19200)

Comment: Could you please tell me a bit more about the pre-allocated buffer? No idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating them as a `Series` instead of a DataFrame, as they are all individuals for now:

```
s1 = pd.Series(np.array([1,2,3,4]), name='Array_1')
s2 = pd.Series(np.array([5,6,7,8]), name='Array_2')
```

Then you can use Pandas to concatenate them into a new `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
# Output
# Array_1   Array_2
#   1         5
#   2         6
#   3         7
#   4         8
```

If all of your arrays are of the same length, you don't need to use `concat` at all:

```
array_1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
array_2 = np.array([5,6,7,8])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Array_1': array_1, 'Array_2': array_2})
```

Comment: So I can make my empty data frame with:
df = pd.DataFrame()
and then add each row at a time by:
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=0) -> axis = 0 as I want arrays as rows
and update my data frame as I go along?

Comment: Your arrays are 1D, so just a long list of values. Assign them to a `Series` each as above, this creates a 'column' filled with all rows of data from the array. Do `print(s1)` to see what it looks like.

Then you can `pd.concat()` them into a single dataframe

Comment: Ah I see, you want them all in the same column? Then yes, change `axis=0`